# csv to array overide data

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to make a array out of a csv file with the header as key. But when I insert the script into a database than it overrides the previous row of the csv file and only the last value gets stored in the database.

I think its because the array has a default value of 5. How can I change the value so that it creates a new value?

This is the script

```
<?php

// open the file.

if (($handle = fopen("test2.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // read the column headers in an array.
    $head = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");


    // read the actual data.
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {



            // create a new array with the elements in $head as keys
            // and elements in array $data as values.
            $combined = array_combine($head,$data);

            // print.
            var_dump($combined);
    }
    // done using the file..close it,
}
?>
```

this is the output

> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Harry" ["description"]=> string(4) "test" ["offer_url"]=> string(42) "demo.com/admin/offers/add" ["preview_url"]=> string(42) "demo.com/admin/offers/add" ["expiration_date"]=> string(9) "23-8-2013" }
>
> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Gerry" ["description"]=> string(4) "test" ["offer_url"]=> string(42) "demo.com/admin/offers/add" ["preview_url"]=> string(42) "demo.com/admin/offers/add" ["expiration_date"]=> string(9) "23-8-2013" }
>
> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "merry" ["description"]=> string(4) "test" ["offer_url"]=> string(42) "demo.com/admin/offers/add" ["preview_url"]=> string(42) "demo.com/admin/offers/add" ["expiration_date"]=> string(9) "23-8-2013" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must go through multidimensional array and add additional index to the combined param like this - combined[]=...:

```
            // create a new array with the elements in $head as keys
            // and elements in array $data as values.
            $combined[] = array_combine($head,$data);
```